# Linux Environment Variables

Tags: linux, shell, environment-variables

I'm trying to change my environment variables using a shell script, but the shell script isn't changing it.

Sorry for asking that type of question, but I'm learning about Linux, I just can't figure out what I'm doing wrong here..

Here's the script

```
export JAVA_HOME=/usr/lib/jvm/jdk1.8.0_60
export PATH=$PATH:$JAVA_HOME/bin
export PATH=$PATH:$JAVA_HOME/jre/bin
```

After I execute this .sh file, when I type

```
echo $PATH
```

It doesn't return the new PATH I setted

Comment: Simply add your lines to `~/.bashrc`. This is a solution how it works but doesn't answer your question.

Comment: but adding to ~/.bashrc it would change permanently...I know I can change it again later, but a shell script would be better in my opinion

Answer (score 3):

Instead of executing it like

```
$ ./script.sh
```

**source** it with

```
$ source script.sh
```

The first variant creates a new process which does not pass back its modified environment variables to the calling process, while sourcing just executes the script within the already running shell.

See also [What is the difference between executing a bash script and sourcing a bash script?](https://superuser.com/questions/176783/what-is-the-difference-between-executing-a-bash-script-and-sourcing-a-bash-scrip)

Comment: There might be a typo (extra backquote?).

Answer (score 1):

As [Andreas](https://stackoverflow.com/a/32495372/841108) explained, you need to source the definition (and you need the `export` to happen in your current shell [process](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Process_%28computing%29), not in a subshell or child process)

You could instead define in your `~/.bashrc` some [shell functions](http://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/html_node/Shell-Functions.html) to do the job:

```
## remember the original path at start of the interactive bash
export ORIGINAL_PATH=$PATH
function prepare_for_java() {
  export JAVA_HOME=/usr/lib/jvm/jdk1.8.0_60
  export PATH=$ORIGINAL_PATH:$JAVA_HOME/bin:$JAVA_HOME/jre/bin
}
function forget_java() {
  unset JAVA_HOME
  export PATH=$ORIGINALPATH
}
```

then in your terminal you would type

```
prepare_for_java
```

before starting doing Java things, and

```
forget_java
```

after you've done with them.

I would suggest to read the [Advanced Bash Scripting Guide](http://tldp.org/LDP/abs/html/) and [Advanced Linux Programming](http://advancedlinuxprogramming.com/) (to get a wider picture).

See also [bash(1)](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man1/bash.1.html), [credentials(7)](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man7/credentials.7.html), [fork(2)](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/fork.2.html), [execve(2)](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/execve.2.html), [environ(7)](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man7/envirion.7.html)